# finding eigenenergy/eigenvector pairs

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

This is perhaps more of a mathematics question rather than a Mathematica one, but I am looking for an easy Mathematica solution. I have a real square matrix consisting of four smaller blocks

$H = \begin{bmatrix}
    A       & -B \\
    B       & -A
\end{bmatrix}$

where $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is asymmetric. It is known that the eigenvalues of such matrices comes in plus/minus pairs. The `Eigensystem` function nicely arrange the eigenvalues in descending order according to their absolute values. This makes it particularly easy to locate a pair of $\pm$ eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors.

```
l = 4;
a = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1.}, l] + 
1.5 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> 1., Band[{2, 1}] -> 1.}, l];
b = 0.5 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> 1., Band[{2, 1}] -> -1.}, l];
h = ArrayFlatten[{{a, -b}, {b, -a}}];
h // Eigenvalues
  {-3.46797, 3.46797, -2.12281, 2.12281, -1.56823, 1.56823, -0.0866172, 0.0866172}
```

The problem arises when $H$ has an extensive number of zero eigenvalues, in this case *Mathematica* no longer arrange the eigenvalue/eigenvector in pairs, like it does for nonzero eigenvalues. The question is how to find the correct zero energy eigenpairs? As a working example:

```
list1 = Riffle[ConstantArray[1., 10], ConstantArray[2., 9]]; 
list2 = Riffle[ConstantArray[1., 10], -ConstantArray[2., 9]];
a = DiagonalMatrix[list1, 1] + DiagonalMatrix[list1, -1];
b = DiagonalMatrix[list2, 1] - DiagonalMatrix[list2, -1];
h = ArrayFlatten[{{a, -b}, {b, -a}}];

h // Eigenvalues // Chop

{5.93852, -5.93852, -5.75584, 5.75584, 5.45723, -5.45723, 5.05172, -5.05172,
 -4.55265, 4.55265, -3.97904, 3.97904, -3.35927, 3.35927, -2.74148, 2.74148,
 -2.22334, 2.22334, -0.00292971, 0.00292971, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Here we have ten pairs of zeroes, how to find the correct $\pm$ pairs?

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes sense. There are ten zero eigenvalues, so there are 10 dimensions in which *any basis at all* can be chosen. In particular, they no longer occur in +/- pairs.

Comment: Presumably, there's some parameter in the Hamiltonian that varies, and for some values of the parameter, there are no zero eigenvalues? You can then find the zero-eigenvalue states that are adiabatically connected to the $\pm$ pairs, perhaps. Are you solving for the dispersion relations of a BEC of some sort?

Comment: If you don't `Chop` your `Eigenvalues` then the pairs of "zeros" are as clear as for the nonzero values. They're all still arranged in pairs.

Comment: @bills my apologies, I will update the question to clarify the pairing. For some $H$ there is exactly one pair of zeroes, regardless of dimension. In that case the $\pm$ pair for the zero eigenmode is obvious. I am trying to extend this to $H$ with many zero pairs.

Comment: @march Indeed, the $H$ with no zero pairs undergoes a phase transition to $H$ with one (or many) zero pairs. States belonging to different phases cannot be adiabatically connected, but I wonder if your approach will still work for finite systems.

Comment: @aardvark2012 The zeroes are not arranged in pairs for large system sizes, regardless of Chop. I will check again.